# I am getting error Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/modulerr (just a hello world app to test)

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am starting to create a view on angular. I tried resting whether angular js properly rendered but get this error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/modulerr

My scripts sequence looks something like this: https://i.ibb.co/VCgrk83/scrpt.png "script sequence"

[image]

Test app like:

```
    <script>
        angular.module("app", []).controller("HelloWorldCtrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "Hello World"
        })
    </script>
```

I JUST GET {{message}} and the expression is not rendered

APP SNAP : https://i.ibb.co/W5QgNBm/scrpt.png

[image]

Thanks for the inputs!!!

[image]

Comment: Try to move your `<script>` tag outside of `<div ng-app>`

Comment: Tried that. No luck. Thanks but still stuck :)

Comment: https://jsbin.com/hedudavema/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yeah Maksym. Definitely works in a seperate example. But was wondering why not with a page that has the above other scripts included. :\ I though somebody would be able to point some silly mistake m doing.

Comment: Any errors or messages in console?

Comment: Yup. This one https://i.ibb.co/gj01Qmc/scrpt.png

Comment: Can you show where are you put `<script src="../angular.js"`? The cause can be that you put  `<script src="../angular.js"` after your script with `angular.module` ...

Comment: Ah this is sort of getting to me. Can't image stucking at this point :(
This is as simple as https://i.ibb.co/3hpK7fs/scrpt.png

Comment: Can you show full page source? And paste it to jsbin, jsfiddle, etc ?

Comment: Its one a the component of an mvc view so it is kind of scattered in places. But I was able to solve the issue by creating a new page and cut-paste all the code bit by bit. Strage by if it works m going ahead with it and will rename the view. Seems i would have to close this one.
Thanks a lot for your involvement Maksym. Appreciate it! :)

Comment: Any updates with this issue?